# Membership.GetUser() using Guid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I found the Membership.GetUser() but it doesn't seem like it supports
retriving user information by the UserId Guid. Does anyone have a nice
and clean way of doing this?

```
public MembershipUser User { // get...;set...;}
```

my code is fail here...

```
User = Membership.GetUser(dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("Id"))); //fail
```

error message: `specified method is not supported`

Comment: what does `dr.GetValue` return?

Comment: @AbuHamzah: Cast or convert it to a Guid variable first then pass it and see if it fails.

Comment: What `MembershipProvider` are you using?

Comment: @Abu Hamzah: See my answer below then, I believe you need to specify whether to update the user's `LastActivityDate` field as part of the `GetUser()` call.

Answer (score 2):

- `Guid.Parse()` and `Guid.TryParse()` are only available in .NET 4.
- You cannot cast a `string` (guessing that's what's returned from `dr.GetValue()` to a `Guid`

So try this instead:

```
MembershipUser m = Membership.GetUser(new Guid(
  dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("Id"))
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the [`Membership.GetAllUsers()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8swhya.aspx) and match [`ProviderUserKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.provideruserkey.aspx) possibly, but @SLaks is correct, ASP uses numeric IDs.

```
foreach (var user in Membership.GetAllUsers())
{
  if ((Guid)user.ProviderUserKey == myguid)
    return user;
}
```

**EDIT** As @MystereMan pointed out, there is an [overload to GetUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152019.aspx) that accepts a Guid:

```
public static MembershipUser GetUser(  
  Object providerUserKey  
)
```

Try casting your `dr` result to a Guid data type, then passing it to the GetUser method (I'm thinking the result back is invalid  or not able to be cast).

```
Guid userId = Guid.Parse(dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("Id"));
MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(userId);
```

Comment: No, One overload of `Getuser` is `public static MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey);`, which takes a ProviderUserKey, which in SqlMembershipProviders case is a Guid.

Comment: @MystereMan: Touché. Shows how often I look up by Guid.

Comment: `if ((Guid)user.ProviderUserKey` there is no ProvderUserKey

Comment: @AbuHamzah: What membership provider are you using then? The default ASP one? Or are you still on ASP .NET 1?

Answer (score 0):

According to what I'm seeing, the base class `MembershipProvider` has a `GetUser()` method overloaded with the signatures:

`GetUser(providerUserKey As Object, userIsOnline As Boolean)`

and

`GetUser(username As String, userIsOnline As Boolean)`

So...maybe you're missing the Boolean?  May be different depending on what provider you're using.  It does look like this holds true for `SqlMembershipProvider`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx

Certainly this must be worth a shot:

```
User = Membership.GetUser(dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("Id")), false); //(!fail)?
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your membership provider settings in your web.config or app.config

e.g.

```
<system.web>
  <membership>
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" .../>
    </providers>
  </membership>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note to future readers:

The SimpleMembershipProvider does not implement the `Membership.GetUser(object providerUserKey)` method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569140(v=vs.111).aspx